# EXCEL TABLE: Find Value based on Latest Date in Column from Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

I am trying to work out how to get a value from a column in an Excel (Office 365) Table based on the latest date from another column which is selected based on multiple criteria.  I have written the formula to get the latest date, now i need to get a corresponding value from another column.  I want to always get the last comment per customer in Column F so for CAMCO it would be Last Note.

An example below:

My formula in Column E is ={MAX(IF([Customer]=B2,[Date]))}

[image]

Comment: which version of Excel?  The answer will vary depending on version

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned version, i am using office 365

Answer (score 0):

To find the latest Note, use

```
=INDEX([Note], MATCH([@Customer] & "_" & MAXIFS([Date], [Customer], [@Customer]), [Customer] & "_" & MAXIFS([Date], [Customer], [@Customer]), 0))
```

Or, if column `Latest Date per Customer` is a perminant addition

```
=INDEX([Note], MATCH([@Customer] & "_" & @[Latest Date per Customer], [Customer] & "_" & [Latest Date per Customer], 0))
```

FYI, your Latest Date lookup is better as

```
=MAXIFS([Date], [Customer], [@Customer])
```

Both are standard (not array) formula