# Getting N/A error on multiple VLOOKUP formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to pull prices from a file to a mixed tender file. My main subjects that I need to search for are POL, Destination City and Container Types. My 2 data sets are as below:

![image: Data I need to add prices]

[image: The main data]

It is just a small portion to show the data type. I have cleaned the data a little bit too. so here is my code for taking the prices :

```
=VLOOKUP(P3,$A$2:$K$251,VLOOKUP(Q3,$A$2:$K$251,VLOOKUP(R3,$A$2:$K$251,5,),),)
```

it didn't work out and I only get error on container types, it cannot find it:

[image: Evaluate Formula]

I am kinda stuck - what should I do? Kindly seeking your help.

Thank you

Comment: You should test each of the three nested `VLOOKUP` calls separately to try to find where it is going wrong.

Comment: The problem is that `VLOOKUP` does not return a column index but the value it found that matches your criteria, i.e. you cannot nest `VLOOKUP`s unless the values being extracted are numbers that correspond to the desired column index. Also, `VLOOKUP` only looks for values inside the first column of your search range. Since you are trying to select data by 3 criteria I would suggest using a simple macro / a user-defined function for this.

Comment: it is on the third one , it always gives error , even if I change the lining up for that one too . I have also changed number with a text like 20 with twenty but it still gives error...

Comment: Looks like you want to find the row that matches all 3 criteria.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56178827/445425) shows a method to do that.  It uses structured references,  but that's easy enough to change to regular range references

Comment: Fyi, when posting sample data, post it as _text_ so we can copy paste it to test with. And include the row and column headers

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `SUMIFS` function instead.

In W3, copied down :

```
=SUMIFS($E:$E,$D:$D,P3,$A:$A,Q3,$B:$B,R3)
```